# Node.js application keeps crashing on Heroku, gives error Boot timeout

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, web-applications, server

I'm developing a sample node.js application and it runs fine locally with

```
node index.js
```

but, when I push it to a Heroku instance, it crashes with the following errors:

> 2017-10-23T06:08:07.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
>   2017-10-23T06:08:16.591817+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node --debug=5858 index.js`
>   2017-10-23T06:08:17.873171+00:00 app[web.1]: Debugger listening on [::]:5858
>   2017-10-23T06:08:18.051769+00:00 app[web.1]: Server listening on port 8080
>   2017-10-23T06:09:16.966905+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
>   2017-10-23T06:09:16.966905+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
>   2017-10-23T06:09:17.062360+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
>   2017-10-23T06:09:17.107893+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
>   2017-10-23T06:09:20.068453+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/contact" host=obscure-meadow-84857.herokuapp.com request_id=69c587a7-ba7f-49d3-8057-4b56338b2d01 fwd="49.35.12.63" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
>   2017-10-23T06:09:20.137463+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=obscure-meadow-84857.herokuapp.com request_id=44f48e7a-94aa-4c10-9578-e8f50f8aeec5 fwd="49.35.12.63" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

My package.json file is set up as follows:

```
{
  "name": "testapp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A little test application",
  "main": "basicRouting.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "ejs": "^2.5.7",
    "express": "^4.16.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "tutorial"
  ],
  "author": "Debaditya Dey",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

Can anyone please help me out regarding this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
2017-10-23T06:09:16.966905+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
```

Please use `process.env.PORT` for your app instead of using your own.

Comment: @TuanAnnTran What if I am not using Express and still getting the same error?

Comment: @neer17just use `process.env.PORT` to bind your server.

Answer (score 2):

In your index.js file, Define your port like this

```
const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log("Server listening on port " + port);
});
```