# Node.js application crashing on Heroku

Tags: node.js, api, heroku, twitter

I have a Nodejs app developed using Twitter API. When hosted on Heroku its giving the following error:

> 2018-12-14T10:00:03.678180+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
>   2018-12-14T10:00:03.678256+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
>   2018-12-14T10:00:03.739029+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137

On searching, I came across these StackOverflow question [q1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15693192/heroku-node-js-error-web-process-failed-to-bind-to-port-within-60-seconds-of) [q2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46883036/node-js-application-keeps-crashing-on-heroku-gives-error-boot-timeout?rq=1) but both of them are using *ExpressJS* and listening onto a fixed port instead of the one provided by Heroku whereas my app is not using *ExpressJS* so, I don't understand where the problem lies. I also ran the app locally using `heroku local` where its working fine. This Heroku article talks about the error but I can't relate it to my app [article](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/error-codes#r10-boot-timeout).
Can anyone explain this error and suggest possible solutions?

**My code**: [code](https://gist.github.com/neer17/bf75d3a114cb311bd2b63b116c2e0345)

Comment: If the code you've provided is the only code, I don't see you starting a server and listening to a port?

Comment: @MaviDomates That is the only code. Do I have to use Express to listen to a port?

Comment: See my answer. In your local machine the code would execute from beginning to end, but in a web-server you'd have to listen to a port.

Comment: @MaviDomates Your solution won't work because the code inside the function passed as the paramter in `createServer` would only run whenever an HTTP request is made to the app whereas in my app no such HTTP request is being made. Instead of this running the app as a worker runs the app perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not using ExpressJS (which you don't have to - it's just a web-server which makes things easier) you should use the regular http server of Node.

See the code below taken from [here](https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/met_server_listen.asp) - slightly edited.

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.write('Hello World!');
  res.end();
}).listen(process.env.PORT || 8080);
```

Answer (score 1):

Heroku checks an app running as a *web* app (as defined in the *Procfile* or by default) for an HTTP request, if it won't find any incoming HTTP request then it would throw the *failed to bind to port error*. For such apps that are meant to run in the background like this Twitter app, run the app as a **worker** by defining a *worker* in the *Procfile*.
For more info to create the *Procfile* visit [procfile](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile). To know more about *web* and *worker* visit [link1](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/process-model) [link2](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/background-jobs-queueing)